# mysql server start aborting innodb at "Waiting for purge to start"

Tags: mysql, innodb, startup

After having upgraded the mysql server on a debian linux to 5.7.13, and the server having successfully started once, so that i could start phpmyadmin, the server eventually shut down. I do not have a clue at the moment to why it first startet, then shut down on it's own decision (?), and in the end is refusing to startup any more.

Syslog reads as follows:

```
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13) starting as process 22976 ...
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 47810183878
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 47810191058
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 47810191058
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
Jun 10 13:34:26 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Apply batch completed
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld[22976]: InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Jun 10 13:34:27 webseiten mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

From previous entries I can see that after that line, the log sequence should continue with something like...

```
Jun 10 12:35:38 webseiten mysqld[14939]: InnoDB: 5.7.13 started; log sequence number 47810025436
Jun 10 12:35:38 webseiten mysqld[14939]: Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Jun 10 12:35:38 webseiten mysqld[14939]: InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
```

...but that doesn't show up anymore.

I have tried - out of pure intuition:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

...but that doesn't help anything.

What is a user expected to do when this happens?

===========================================

Deleted the whole database /var/lib/mysql/.
Played back a backup from before the upgrade.
Restarted the server. Worked for the moment.
Complained however about "innodb_force_recovery".
Removed that from my.cnf.

Tried to restart: Failure again!
But this time with other messages (from last successful step to begin of abort sequence):

```
Jun 10 14:38:42 webseiten mysqld[27097]: InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Jun 10 14:38:42 webseiten mysqld[27097]: InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9, and we did not find a valid checkpoint. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html
Jun 10 14:38:42 webseiten mysqld[27097]: InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
Jun 10 14:38:43 webseiten mysqld[27097]: Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jun 10 14:38:43 webseiten mysqld[27097]: Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jun 10 14:38:43 webseiten mysqld[27097]: Failed to initialize plugins.
Jun 10 14:38:43 webseiten mysqld[27097]: Aborting
```

...Will try to make something up of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html...

==============================

Old version was 5.5.47... Thus, according to "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html", it is not supported for upgrade to 5.7.xx.
(a server not being upgraded for years - you don't ever finish learning!)

-> Going to downgrade, export from there, then upgrade again, then import (this will take hours)...

=============================

Executed...

```
apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common
```

...deleting all config and data files.
Executed...

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

...to receive version 5.5.49.

Trying to start (on a completely purged base), this gives errors:

```
Jun 10 15:24:17 webseiten mysqld_safe[3503]: 160610 15:24:17 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
Jun 10 15:24:17 webseiten mysqld_safe[3503]: 
Jun 10 15:24:17 webseiten mysqld_safe[3503]: Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
Jun 10 15:24:17 webseiten mysqld_safe[3503]: /var/lib/mysql for more information.
```

Looking at '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys', this shows up as being owned by mysql, having "rw-r--r--". - No clue what could possibly hinder a user "mysql" from accessing it, having all directories above having execute right for all.

/var/lib/mysql/ has no log files (why should it?)!

==========================

Well: Purge didn't delete the config file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf). And that file still has some entries for the newer 5.7.13 version (well: the installer did in fact create a new version of that config, but seemingly incorporated some entries from the previous version)...

=========================

Now, we have:

```
160610 15:44:30 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.49-0+deb7u1) starting as process 4551 ...
160610 15:44:30 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
160610 15:44:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Unknown error 1146
160610 15:44:30 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160610 15:44:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160610 15:44:30  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160610 15:44:31 InnoDB: 5.5.49 started; log sequence number 1595675
160610 15:44:31 [ERROR] Aborting

160610 15:44:31  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160610 15:44:32  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160610 15:44:32 [Note] 
160610 15:44:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I have no clue as to why this "messagefile" shall be unreadable by user mysql. 
I have no clue how to run mysql_upgrade without the server having started.
And I have no clue, what an "Unknown error 1146" shall be...

My IT-chef comes up with the idea, that the message files possibly did not downgraded to 5.5, but could instead still be for version 5.7, and thus be technically well "not readable" by the server process. Meaning that "not readable" is something different from "not readable" as it is commonly used for "not accessable"...

Thus the problem developed down to "how do I downgrade this message files?"...

...Well: Downgrading the message file to version 5.5.50 didn't help either. Still "not readable".